How to type a prop which is an Astro Component with Typescript?
I'm passing an Astro component through prop. I'd like to know how should I type it with Typescript. Keep in mind that the component I'm passing is different in each instance.
ServiceItem.astro
---
interface Props {
/* How should I type this?? It is an astro component and is a different component in each instance */
  Icon: any;
  title: string;
  descriptionItems: string[];
}

const { Icon, title, descriptionItems } = Astro.props;
---

<div class="flex flex-col items-center text-center p-2 bg-transparent rounded-lg md:flex-row md:gap-x-5 md:text-left">
  <div class="mb-4">
    <Icon />
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3 class="text-2xl font-bold mb-2 uppercase">{title}</h3>
    <ul class="ul-style-type-custom text-left">
        {descriptionItems.map(item => (
            <li class="pl-2">{item}</li>
        ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
    .ul-style-type-custom {
        list-style-type: "-";
    }
</style>

Searching on internet there is a suggestion that we could use the "FunctionComponent" from react but since I'm not using react in my astro project I don't plan to install it as a dependency.
Any idea how to solve this?

I think you cannot do that with astro components like that (regardless of TypeScript). You need to use a slot instead.

It works, the component passed as a prop is rendered properly

okay, so what is the type when you hover over it in VSCode at the call-site?

I could find a type for this situation which is AstroComponentFactory.
import type { AstroComponentFactory } from "astro/runtime/server/index.js";

The only drawback is that you have to pass the component function and not an instance of it (just like you have it). Apparently, you can't use JSX inside Astro component props, it is a limitation of the Astro compiler, as per one of its maintainers.
